# Reading cell value without redefining it with Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I need to read this `.xlsm` database and some of the cells values I need are derived from Excel functions. To accomplish this I used:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('file.xlsm', data_only=True, keep_vba=True)
ws = wb['Plan1']
```

And then, for every cell I wanted to read:

```
ws.cell(row=row, column=column).value
```

This works fine for getting the data out. But the problem comes with saving. When I do:

```
wb.save('file.xlsm')
```

It saves the file, but all the formulas inside the sheets are lost

My dilemma is reading the cell's displayed values on one of the database's sheet without modifying them, writing the code's output in a new sheet and saving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the file once in read-only and data-only mode to look at the values and another time keeping the VBA around. And save under a different name.

Comment: Really simple. I wonder how I didn't think of that before. Thanks